# Kivy - Create app using a website url

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have a responsive website www.xyz.com.

Is it possible to create an android app using Kivy (apk) and have the url browsing experience in an app like environment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could technically do it using Kivy like https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-native-embedded-browser . However, using Kivy here is not a great idea considering that it can be done easily using the [webview](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) from Android Studio or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, kivy is a framework for building cross platform Apps. You can re-build your website with kivy. But in your case, its a huge overhead, because you can just put the html of your website in a Web View and run it like an App.

You can doit easily with [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)

Cheers

Comment: Since my site is built on Django framework, will the backend functionality work with the app.And could you if possible give me an example how to put website in a webview and run it as app

Comment: okey, I never did something whit django, but as far as I know it's a server side framework for building websites in python, like symfony in PHP.. 
You can put the resulted HTML (which you get from django) and put it as plain html into the webView

Comment: It's a statical website, right? So you can generate the html and save it somewhere. Then look into cordova, there are tons of examples how to create HTML5 Apps with it.

Comment: If it's ok, that your app will be visible only when the user is online, then, you can just create a simple iOS application, which is loading the WebView with your url (www.xyz.com)

Comment: fortunately its a dynamic site. for example : making orders, contact us etc.

Comment: Ok, then just create an WebView with an URL in it. To understand it, here is a link http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/ This means your app, will be like a browser without the address bar ;) For android it is the same